# Adding data to complex state in react reducer

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a react reducer that manages the following kind of state

```
const exampleState: INote[][] = [
  [
    { x: 3, y: 5, value: '4' },
    { x: 3, y: 6, value: '4' },
  ],
  [
    { x: 7, y: 3, value: '4' },
    { x: 8, y: 5, value: '7' },
    { x: 8, y: 5, value: '6' }
  ],
];
```

So a 2D array that contains arrays of a specific type of object. For some reason I can't figure out how to update this kind of state. I want to specifically be able to add a new instance (without mutating original state) of INote to a specific nested array. How can I achieve this? The index of the array I need to add the object to is in my reducers action object

Comment: cant you just `concat()` an array to the array of arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the obvious ways would be to update this state immutably, for instance, let's say I have a `ADD_NOTE` action, it could look something like that:

`{type: "ADD_NOTE", payload: { item: INote, index: number }}`

And then, an example return statement of the reducer for this action would be:

`return state.map((arr, i) => i === index ? [...arr, item] : arr)`

This will update the array, and will add `item` to the end of the array with the provided action index.

Another solution that might make your life easier is to use help libraries such as https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper or https://github.com/immerjs/immer

Comment: `return state.map((arr, i) => i === index ? [...arr, item] : arr)` Was just what I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an array of `objects` instead of array of `arrays` so you can add an `identifier` such as an `id` to each `object` so you can update that specific `object` based on its `id`